# Path of Cookie not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I want to create a cookie to store a class so I can use this through the whole site. I checked the cookies, and the cookie is created. The problem is when the cookie is set on another page the path is /url-page en not /

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  values = $.map($('select option'), function(e) { return e.value; });
  $('#color-select').on('change', function() {
    $("body").removeClass(values.join(" ")).addClass( (""  + $('#color-select').val()) );
    var foobar =(""  + $('#color-select').val());
    document.cookie = "gsscookie=" + foobar, "expires=;domain=;path=/";
  })
});
```

I'm working on a local dev environment with the url plastic.dev.local. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How come you're parsing the value to a string when inputs are already strings?

Comment: Is the other page also using `path=/`? All pages have to do this, because the default is always the current path.

Comment: @Barmar, yes the script is triggered again on the other pages. So it will use  `path=/` again.

Comment: So this is an external JS file that's loaded on all the pages?

Comment: Do any of them have their own code that also sets the same cookie? If they set the cookie twice, and some of them don't have a path, the more specific path will take precedence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value that gets assigned to `document.cookie` should be a single string, with a semicolon after the "key=value" assignment, and then semicolons between each property that you're setting on the cookie. The way you're doing it, with the comma after the first string, makes it so the second string is basically ignored. If you change it to `document.cookie = "gsscookie=" + foobar + ";expires=;domain=;path=/";`, it should work.

Comment: Thanks Elezar, That's the solution!!

Comment: You may need to URL Encode the `foobar` variable, though.